Nestjs docker run Error: Cannot find module @nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
I'm creating a RestAPI in nestJS following the microservice pattern. After Integrating Docker for the project, I'm unable to run the different Services on the Docker container. As of now, I've added auth and reservations services. below are the respective DockerFiles.
Dockerfile for auth service
FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml tsconfig.json nest-cli.json ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm


RUN pnpm install


COPY . .
# COPY apps/auth apps/auth
# COPY libs libs


RUN pnpm run build auth

FROM node:alpine As production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install --prod

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/apps/auth/main.js"]


Dockerfile for reservations service
FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml tsconfig.json nest-cli.json ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install


COPY . .
# COPY apps/reservations apps/reservations
# COPY libs libs


RUN pnpm run build reservations

FROM node:alpine As production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install --prod

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/apps/reservations/main.js"]


Here's the stacktrace of the Error log on Reservations container. both the containers have the same problem.
2024-10-23 13:41:20 
2024-10-23 13:41:20 > reserve-sytem@0.0.1 start:dev /usr/src/app
2024-10-23 13:41:20 > nest start --watch "reservations"
2024-10-23 13:41:20 
2024-10-23 13:41:20 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1262
2024-10-23 13:41:20   throw err;
2024-10-23 13:41:20   ^
2024-10-23 13:41:20 
2024-10-23 13:41:20 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
2024-10-23 13:41:20     at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:15)
2024-10-23 13:41:20     at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1085:27)
2024-10-23 13:41:20     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
2024-10-23 13:41:20     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
2024-10-23 13:41:20     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
2024-10-23 13:41:20     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:36:49 {
2024-10-23 13:41:20   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-10-23 13:41:20   requireStack: []
2024-10-23 13:41:20 }
2024-10-23 13:41:20 
2024-10-23 13:41:20 Node.js v23.0.0
2024-10-23 13:44:15 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1262
2024-10-23 13:44:15   throw err;
2024-10-23 13:44:15   ^
2024-10-23 13:44:15 
2024-10-23 13:44:15 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
2024-10-23 13:44:15     at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:15)
2024-10-23 13:44:15     at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1085:27)
2024-10-23 13:44:15     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
2024-10-23 13:44:15     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
2024-10-23 13:44:15     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
2024-10-23 13:44:15     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:36:49 {
2024-10-23 13:44:15   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-10-23 13:44:15   requireStack: []
2024-10-23 13:44:15 }
2024-10-23 13:44:15 
2024-10-23 13:44:15 Node.js v23.0.0
2024-10-23 13:41:20  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
2024-10-23 13:44:15 
2024-10-23 13:44:15 > reserve-sytem@0.0.1 start:dev /usr/src/app
2024-10-23 13:44:15 > nest start --watch "reservations"
2024-10-23 13:44:15 
2024-10-23 13:44:15  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.


Would appreciate any support possiable.
Project Repository Can be Accessed from Here Here

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the dockr-compose.yaml, where removing the volumes in the different services.
I found the answer based on this suggestion
